# What will happen two different background process access the same file in unix?

Tags: multithreading, shell, unix, process

Please explain me on the below cmd:

```
touch temp.txt
touch temp1.txt
who > temp.txt &
cat temp.txt | wc -l >temp1.txt  &
```

say about temp.txt file is a empty file.
So, what will present in `temp.txt` and `temp1.txt` files after the execution.

Could somebody explain the possible cases, since the jobs are running in background mode?

Comment: It depends. Generally: bad things.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour will happen.

Comment: and nothing particularly different than what would happen if two foreground processes access the same file. Timing and buffering will both play a role in the non deterministic results.

Comment: Ok so basically there is difference between writing and accessing. Here you write only to temp.txt and READ temp.txt after that, so nothing bad will happen. You will number of lines in one file and who output in the second one. That is it. Background jobs here are fast, they do something and finish, so there is no really parallelism here.  If they are always runing then we can think of different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The state of `temp.txt` when `cat` is run is out of your control (it's up to the scheduler when `cat` and `who` run relative to each other), so you can't predict what will happen. A safer version is

```
# These two commands are unnecessary. The files will be created
# when opened for writing.
# touch temp.txt
# touch temp1.txt
who | tee temp.txt | wc -l > temp1.txt &  # If it really needs to run in the background
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  `cat(1)` might see something or nothing in its input file.

Here's a very rough picture of what's going on in the final two commands.  (I'm ignoring the `touch(1)` calls because they are synchronous.)

- `who >f1`
  A child is forked, the output file clobbered, the output file moved to child's stdout, and a new program is run.
- `cat f2 | wc -l>f2`
  A child is forked, a pipe made, another child forked, the children move their pipe ends to stdin or stdout as appropriate, one child runs a command which will open the input file, the other child clobbers output and so on as above.

I don't guarantee that that's actually what your shell is doing -- maybe it clobbers *before* it forks, etc. -- but that's close enough.  So, let's put these shell commands on a time dimension:

```
[time =====================================================================>]

# who >f1
-?->[clobber *f1*]-?->[dup to stdout]-?->[exec who(1)]-?->[...]

# cat f1 | wc -l>f2
-?->[pipe]-?->[fork]-?->[dup pipe]-?->[clobber *f2*]-?->[dup to stdout]-?->[exec wc(1)]
                +----?->[dup pipe]-?->[exec cat(1)]-?->[open *f1*]-?->[...]
```

Every one of the `-?->` arrows above may be arbitrarily long or short -- you cannot control that.  Maybe `cat(1)` is run *before* the very first clobber (seeing old data?), maybe not.  Maybe it is run before `who(1)` has a chance to write output, maybe not.